# Probability, making a selection of 5 people from 10, with two married couples with restrictions

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

> 10 people. must make a committee of 5 people

*So the restrictions are*

> 1) Mr and Mrs Q can't be separated
>
> 2) Mr and Mrs P can't be in the same committee.

So how many possible committees can you form.

4 CASES:

**CASE 1: No P AND no Q's**

$$ \binom{6}{5}=6 $$

**CASE 2: Q's AND NO P**

$$ \binom{6}{3} = 20 $$

**CASE 3: 1P and Q's**

$$ \binom{6}{2} * 2=30$$

**CASE 4: 1P and NO Q's**
$$ \binom{6}{4}*2=30 $$

86 possible committees

Am I doing this correctly?

Comment: The second restriction is phrased in a strange way. "Mr. and Mrs. P can't be on the same committee" suggests that there will be multiple committees, and that Mr. and Mrs. P must be on different committees (if both are on a committee). I wonder why it wasn't phrased as "Mr. and Mrs. P can't both be on the committee."

Comment: Sorry thats just my writing. The full question is : There are two married couples amongst the group of ten: Mr and Mrs P, and
Mr and Mrs Q. When a committee of ve is formed, since Mr and Mrs P argue all the time, at
most one of these two can be chosen, whereas Mr and Mrs Q are inseparable, so a committee
must either contain both of Mr and Mrs Q or else neither of them.
With these constraints, now how many distinct ve-person committees can be formed? @CameronBuie

Comment: Gotcha. In that case, I'll upvote your question and Ross's answer, since they're right on track.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The title on case 1 should be no P's or Q's.  Some of the others may be married, but you don't care.  The logic is fine.

Comment: Ok thanks. But is my maths correct?

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: Thank you Ross, very helpful